# How to set my terminal to use solarized palette?

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, plugin-solarized

I've set up cygwin on my PC, now I want to configure vim to use solarized color scheme. I'm following the github page: https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.

there's a section: IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS in the page, advising the terminal user better to use the solarized palette. But after reading, I still don't have a clue how to do it. Could some help here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the configuration of some terminal emulator program.

Comment: You can find the list of supported terminal emulators on the [Solarized home page](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized#terminal-emulators). Then, if supported, you can refer to the documentation of your terminal emulator to know how to set up Solarized.

Answer (score 3):

That part of the documentation explains it.

> I've included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from [Solarized homepage](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).

You need to use one of [these palettes](https://github.com/altercation/solarized) depending on the terminal client you're using.

This is unrelated to vim.